# C++ syntax, difference between i % k == l % k == 0 and i % k == 0 && l % k == 0

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the semantic difference between these syntax structures.

```
 if ((i% k) == (l % k) == 0)
```

and

```
if ((i % k) == 0 && (l % k) == 0)
```

Comment: You do know what those expessions are quirte filed with ... expressions, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your specific expressions (`(i % k)` and `(l % k)` ) are irrelevant for the question. It can be rephrased like: "given `int a, b;`, what is the difference between `a==b==0` and `a==0 && b==0`.

The first of these expressions (`a==b==0`) is almost certainly not what you meant (this is not Python!). It is equivalent to `(a==b)==0`, which in turn is equivalent to `a!=b`.

The second one (`a==0 && b==0`) is what you expect: "both `a` and `b` are zero".

Answer (score 1):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is a good place to check on c++ operator precedence and associativity.

Since `==` operator has left-to-right associativity, your first expression is equivalent to

```cpp
if (((i % k) == (l % k)) == 0)
```

which first checks whether `(i % k) == (l % k)`, which evaluates to a `bool`, and then compare the `bool` to zero. A bool `== 0` when it is `false`. Thus, it is also equivalent to:

```cpp
if ((i % k) != (l % k))
```

Note you can also remove parentheses around the modulo operation, because `%` has higher precedence than `==`.

Your second example might be what you really want: checking whether both `(i % k) == 0` and `(l % k) == 0`.